# Where is the android signing key on the disk that Xamarin Studio creates?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm publishing using a key that I created in Xamarin Studio. Where is that key on the disk so I can take a backup of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

windows is in 
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore

OS X is in
~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/